# IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying redirect a URL **https://site1.com/uploads/test.zip** to **https://site2.com/uploads/samples/uploads/test.zip**. But it always showing error. What I'm doing wrong?

[image: Trying to redirect following URL]

[image: Test Pattern]

Comment: This site is hosted as sub application in IIS. Is there any problem?

Comment: "But it always showing error." What error?

Comment: Showing 404 for the same url.

Comment: "I am trying to redirect" - but in the dropdown for Action, you have selected rewrite. Which is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for you because your pattern is incorrect. When you testing your pattern, you shouldn't put full URL (https://site1.com/uploads/test.zip), you should put only "uploads/test.zip".

If you want to redirect single URL `https://site1.com/uploads/test.zip` then you shouldn't even write pattern. You can just make a rule like that:
[image]